# Can't set property via .props file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to change project's property via .props file. I created 2 files:

**Directory.build.props**

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
        <ForceImportBeforeCppProps>$(MsbuildThisFileDirectory)\MyProps.props</ForceImportBeforeCppProps>
        <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.19041.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And

**MyProps.props**

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
        <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
        <PreferredToolArchitecture>x86</PreferredToolArchitecture>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
        <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
        <PreferredToolArchitecture>x86</PreferredToolArchitecture>
    </PropertyGroup>
        <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
        <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <PreferredToolArchitecture>x86</PreferredToolArchitecture>
    </PropertyGroup>
        <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
        <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <PreferredToolArchitecture>x86</PreferredToolArchitecture>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Both properties **WindowsTargetPlatformVersion** and **PlatformToolset** are successfully applied, but not the **PreferredToolArchitecture**. Could  you please tell me, where I'm wrong? How to set it properly? I', using **Visual Studio 2019**

I also found, that this works if I delete **PreferredToolArchitecture** property from the .vcxproj file. Why it can't override it?

Answer (score 0):

'Directory.build.props' is imported early, before the main body of the project file. The `ForceImportBeforeCppProps` property instructs that your 'MyProps.props' file should be imported early.

The `PreferredToolArchitecture` property in the .vcxproj is overriding your definition.

Move your property overrides to a 'Directory.build.targets' file.